# "Rethrow" to next catch clause

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

If there is a try-catch with mutiple catch-blocks, is there way to rethrow an exception to next (not underlaying) catch-clause?

Example:

```
try {

  // some exception can occur here

} catch (MyException ex) {

  // do something specific

  // rethrow ex to next catch

} catch (Exception ex) {

  // do logging stuff and other things to clean everything up
}
```

When a `MyException` is thrown, I want to handle the specific stuff to that exception but then I want to handle exceptions in general (`catch (Exception ex)`).

I don't want to use a finally-block and Java 7 Multi-catch is also no help here.

Any ideas how to handle this, I want to avoid redundant stuff in each catch-block. Is it better to catch `Exception` only and then use `instanceof` for my specific stuff?

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what's wrong with the `finally` clause?

Comment: nothing is wrong with finally!! This allows you to execute code that should run with or without the exception

Comment: @aga Well... it's triggered in all cases, not just when exceptions have occurred.

Comment: and thats not what you want :) clear

Comment: yes, I need something like finally-exception :P

Comment: OK, now I understand. I had to read the question carefully, not just from the bird's eye view. :)

Comment: this is like not "break" in "switch". And neither of solutions does that clean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void doStuff()
{
   try
   {

     // some exception can occur here

   } catch (MyException ex){

     // do something specific

     cleanupAfterException(ex);

   } catch (Exception ex) {

     cleanupAfterException(ex);
   }
}

private void cleanupAfterException(Exception ex)
{
   //Do your thing!
}
```

I presume something like this would do?

Comment: In principle this would be fine, but I tend to avoid such patterns as it's too easy for the `generalStuff(ex);` statement to be omitted or deleted by mistake.

Comment: @DuncanJones If by that, you mean the method name is too general or undescriptive, then it's obviously just a placeholder name. Else, I don't quite follow.

Comment: looks like a clean solution, but now it's maybe a bit ugly to handle method specific clean up stuff

Comment: @RenéJensen I'm always cautious of patterns that rely on future maintainers doing the right thing when adding extra catch clauses etc. There's nothing wrong with what you're suggesting, just a personal preference.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try something like this:

```
try
{

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    if(ex instanceof MyException)
    {
        // Do your specific stuff.
    }
    // Handle your normal stuff.
}
```

Comment: yes, I suggested this as a possible way, but I wasn't sure, wether this is good style :)

Comment: I don't see why not. You're just checking the type of the Exception.

Comment: You might find sources that say it's a bad practice, but from what I could find is that it is only a bad practice if you actually change the object you're checking the type of. So basically, you have a part of that class outside of the actual class. The way I understand your question though, is that in this case you don't alter anything in the `MyException`, and just want to check the type.

Answer (score 1):

You could just nest your `try` statements:

```
try {
  try {

    // some exception can occur here

  } catch (MyException ex) {

    // do something specific

    // rethrow ex to next catch

  }
}  catch (Exception ex) {

  // do logging stuff and other things to clean everything up
}
```

Although I worry this is what you mean when you say "*(not underlaying)*"?

Comment: @FrecherxDachs There's nothing implicitly wrong with nesting try/catch statements if you have a good reason. In your example, I would say it was preferable to a bunch of `instanceof` checks.

Comment: But then the rethrow of MyException then get caught by the outer catch and not seen further up the stack trace which seems to be what the question requires.

Comment: You are probably right, might be a good solution for this, but in my opinion nesting try-statments reduces readability of code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try multiple try catch:

```
try {

} catch(MyException ex) {
    try {

    } catch(Exception ex) {

    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I also got this in mind, but is it good style to nest try-catch-block?

Comment: @FrecherxDachs you are not willing to use finally then i think this is an alternate or Duncan Jones answer

Answer (score 0):

Surely this is what functions are for?

```
try {
    doStuff();
} catch ( MyException e ) {
    doMyExceptionStuff();
    doGeneralExceptionStuff();
    throw e;
} catch ( Exception e ) {
    doGeneralExceptionStuff();
}
```